Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)... Migrating from React-router to NextJs
The code below works well in react-router-dom but causes issue in Nextjs. I can't figure out what's wrong with the code in nextjs standards.
While trying to render a Header Component from 'src\components\Header\index.jsx' into Layout file at 'src\app\layout.js', I get this error message:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Header`.

Header/index.jsx looks like:
"use client"

import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from "next/link";
import xmark from './../../assets/xmark.svg';
import bar from './../../assets/lines.svg';
// import settings from './../../components/config.jsx'

export function Header() {
  const links = [{ text: "Home", link: './' }, { text: "About", link: './about' }, { text: "Contact", link: './contact' }, { text: "Blogs", link: "blog_address" }];
  const linkRender = Array.from(links).map((item, index) => { return (<Link key={index} to={item.link} className="m-4 hover:drop-shadow-[0.2em_0.3em_5px_#000]">{item.text}</Link>) })
  const small_linkRender = Array.from(links).map((item, index) => { return (<li id={index} key={index}><Link to={item.link} className="m-4 hover:drop-shadow-[0.2em_0.3em_5px_#000]">{item.text}</Link></li>) })
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  function grey_click(e) {
    if (e.target == document.getElementById('whitespace') || e.target == document.getElementById('list_parent') || Number.isInteger(parseInt(e.target.id))) return;
    setIsOpen(prev => false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/** Navigation model for large devices */}
      <nav id='med+' className='hidden md:flex justify-between w-full h-10 bg-gray-300'>
        <div className='mt-auto mb-auto ml-20 flex'><img className='mr-2' alt='Logo' src='./logo.png'></img><span>Fatema Image Consultancy</span></div>
        <div className='mt-auto mb-auto mr-20'>{linkRender}</div>
      </nav>

      {/** Navigation model for small devices */}
      <nav id='small' className='md:hidden flex  w-full h-10 bg-gray-300'>
        <div></div>
        <div className='mt-auto ml-5 grow justify-center mb-auto flex'><img className='mr-2' alt='Logo' src='./logo.png'></img><span className='hidden vsm:block'>Fatema Image Consultancy</span><span className='vsm:hidden'>Fatema Consultant</span></div>
        <div className='mt-auto mb-auto mr-4'>
          <img src={bar} onClick={() => setIsOpen(prev => true)} className='w-5 h-5'></img>
          <div onClick={grey_click} className={`fixed top-0 right-0 w-screen h-screen bg-black/50 duration-500 ${isOpen ? '' : 'invisible bg-black/0'}`}>
            <div id="whitespace" className={`fixed right-0 top-0 ${isOpen ? '' : 'translate-x-48'} w-[10.75rem] h-screen bg-white duration-500 ease-out`}>
              <ul id="list_parent" className='mt-9 text-center'>{small_linkRender}</ul>
              <img src={xmark} className='absolute top-2 w-5 h-5'></img>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  )
}


Part of the code giving me error:
const links = [{ text: "Home", link: './' }, { text: "About", link: './about' }, { text: "Contact", link: './contact' }, { text: "Blogs", link: "blog_address" }];
const linkRender = Array.from(links).map((item, index) => { return (<Link key={index} to={item.link} className="m-4 hover:drop-shadow-[0.2em_0.3em_5px_#000]">{item.text}</Link>) })
const small_linkRender = Array.from(links).map((item, index) => { return (<li id={index} key={index}><Link to={item.link} className="m-4 hover:drop-shadow-[0.2em_0.3em_5px_#000]">{item.text}</Link></li>) })

What I've Tried:
I had tried many things before but question has since changed and the info is irrelevant. Thanks to @rev0manana for pointing it out.

According to the error, it's not an issue about import, but related to what your component is returning.
Make sure to check if there's any rendering condition in Header that returns undefined. We might help if you show more of the Header's component code

I removed everything from Header file, leaving it just with default template I used in the question above and I still have the same error. So, It's definitely not the code in Header file causing issue. Do you know of anything else that could make code in Header file to be rendered as undefined?
Btw thanks for helping, but you should post this as comment and not an answer.

I think i found the issue, You are rending your Header inside the Layout file but not in the right place, it should be inside the body tag, Next will have hydration issue if you render it outside the body, which is normal btw semantically.

still no luck!  Putting Header in import statement gives error in question and {Header} still gives Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined.

Actually, sorry. you were right. problem was in one of the variables defined in Header page. I might've not given it enough time to reload when I tried replacing the entire code with the template I've mentioned. I have updated the question to now include the variables giving me trouble. will give the code to header file too.

Another Update: so finally I realized, the main issue was me calling Link component of React using { Link } and notLink smh. I'm so annoyed at this mistake rn but thanks for the help! also since your answer helped me identify problem, I'll mark it as answer.
